# Erro com sintaxe no Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

Estou praticando um exercício do curso e me deparei com o seguinte erro abaixo. Estou utilizando o Python 3.7. Qual o problema nesta digitação?

```
convite = 'Flavio Henrique Almeida'
parte1 = convite[0:4]
parte2 = convite[11:15]
print "%s %s" % (parte1, parte2)
```

Erro:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
  print "%s %s" % (parte1, parte2)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

O erro está no `print "%s %s" % (parte1, parte2)`. No Python 3 você precisa colocar os argumentos do `print` entre parênteses `(`, `)`, como qualquer outra chamada de função.

No caso ficaria assim:

```
print("%s %s" % (parte1, parte2))
```